# Why mongoose replaces subdocuments with "[object Object]"?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm encountering weird behavior with embedded docs and I don't know if I do something wrong or is it a bug.

This is my model:

```
var mg = require('mongoose')
 , S  = mg.Schema;

var subject = new S({
    name: String
  , properties: [{
        name: String
      , value: String
    }]
});

module.exports = mg.model('Subject',subject);
```

When I try to add a property, it somehow gets converted into `"[object Object]"`:

```
  console.log(req.body); // --> { name: 'height', value: 120 }
  console.log(typeof req.body); // --> object
  ob.Subject.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$push: {properties: req.body}}, function(err, doc) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(doc);
  });
```

The returned `doc` is:

```
{_id: '...', name: 'sss', properties:[ "[object Object]" ]}
```

I used mongo CLI to inspect the document in the database and put proper values in it.

```
//the document as seen in mongo CLI:
{
  _id: '...', name: 'sss', 
  properties: [ "[object Object]", {name: "aaa", value: "bar"} ]
}
```

Then I tried this:

```
ob.Subject.findById(id, function(err, doc) {
  res.send(doc);
}
```

And then the returned doc is:

```
{ 
  _id: '...', name: 'sss', 
  properties:[ "[object Object]", "[object Object]" ]
}
```

I think that, what's happening is mongoose somehow converts the subdocument into this string. Moreover, I don't think that this is my, or `res.send()` fault because:

- I'm not using `toJson` or `toObject` explicitly, I don't handle JSON conversion at all
- `res.send()` is not an issue because even if I `util.inspect` the value - it's the same
- invalid conversion seems to happen both at write and read via mongoose

Have you ever encountered similar behavior? Is there a way around that?

I just started with mongoose and don't have an idea how to fallback to mongodb native to update and fetch documents and check if this behavior persists (I doubt).

Any helpful hints appreciated :)

Comment: Same here. I have found that if you define your subdocument as a Schema, something like var subject = new S({
    name: String
  , properties: [SubSchema]
});

Then it works fine...

Doesn't seem too correct for me, as I was defining it as an object, because just need ONE instance (not a collection) and ended having to use an array of Schemas since Schemas can only be nested in Mongoose if you embed them in an array... did you find a more proper solution for this?

Comment: `Is there a way around that?` - Yes, it is called [bug report](https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose/issues).

Answer (score 1):

Even though Node.js and MongoDB both use Javascript they do not share the same memory space. They're not even running in the same process.
Thus they have to talk over tcp and serialize data.

I would assume your `req.body` is getting `toString()`'ed when formatting the request for mongoDB.

*EDIT*

This is normal because you declared the `properties` attribute of your model as an array of strings.

Just declare it like this:

```
properties: Object
```

Comment: But the same thing happens when I put a proper subdoc in the document, using CLI and then try to read the document using mongoose. And the subdocument looks normal in the CLI. Only it's value gets converted into `"[object Object]"` somewhere in `find`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your 'properties' property is defined wrong. I understand what you are trying to do, but I suspect you need to define the key/value pair as a type of it's own so that your code becomes:

```
    var mg = require('mongoose')
     , S  = mg.Schema;

    var keyValue = new S({
        key: String, value: String});

    var subject = new S({
        name: String
      , properties: [keyValue]
    });

    module.exports = mg.model('Subject',subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
ob.Subject.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$push: {properties: {name: req.body.name, value: req.body.value}}}, function(err, doc) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(doc);
});
```